# Close page alongside bottom sheet without calling Navigator.pop twice in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a bottom sheet inside a page. Inside a bottom sheet, I want that if its tapped, it closes both the sheet and the page. What I used to achieve this is calling  `Navigator.pop(context)` twice. However, this affects the performance of the app as the navigation isn't really smooth. Are there other options to achieving this?

```
                           CustomButton2(
                            text: 'Check out other fleets',
                            width: 85.0,
                            onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.pop(context); //closes bottom sheet
                            Navigator.pop(context); //closes page to reveal previous screen
                            },
                            color: greenColor,
                            textSize: 18),
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what do you want to achieve.
If it is to go back to a certain named page or Route in the Navigation Stack,
you can use the function below

```
Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName("Foo"))
```

This will automatically pop to a certain Route with the name given without "actually" popping twice.

If you do not want to use it, and it doesn't answer your problem, you can actually achieve it by popping twice just like you did. It will run more smoothly if it were on the release build.

More Info in https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html